# About the octonions

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, octonions

Given $a\in \mathbb R^3-\{0\}$, then the map $J_a: q\to q\frac{a}{|a|}$ is a complex structure of the quaternions $\mathbb H$.

Now, what about the octonions $\mathbb O$? Do they similarly obtain a complex structure?

Comment: Not only that, but every pair of orthogonal imaginary octonions generates a copy of the quaternions, yielding a quaternionic structure. These facts can be straightforwardly verified, and are important to classifying subalgebras of the octonions (and arguably, in classifying real normed division algebras themselves).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a [*linear* complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure#Definition_and_properties), yes. Each $a\in\Bbb R^7\setminus\{0\}$ can be interpreted as an "imaginary" octonion, so as to satisfy $a^2=-|a|^2$, with $|a|$ the length of the original vector. Hence$$q\frac{a}{|a|}\frac{a}{|a|}=q\frac{a^2}{|a|^2}=-q.$$